# Mono in Flux by single thread

Tags: java, mono, flux, project-reactor, reactor

I have `Flux<Foo>` from db (for example 5 elements).
I need to get some info from each Foo, set all of it to `Mono<MyRequest>`, send to another rest resource, get a `Mono<MyResponse>` and use all info from it in each Foo.

I did it in `Flux.flatMap()` with a lot `Mono.zipWith()` and `Mono.zipWhen()`, **but creating MyRequest and sending to resource occur 5 times by 5 threads.**

```
Flux<Foo> flux = dao.getAll();
Flux<Foo> fluxAfterProcessing = flux.flatMap(foo -> monoFilters.map(...));
Mono<Tuple2<MyRequest, MyResponse>> mono = 
                      monoFilters.flatMap(filter -> monoRequest.map(...))
                                 .zipWhen(request -> api.send(request))
                                 .flatMap(tuple -> monoResponseFilters.map(...));
return fluxAfterProcessing.flatMap(foo -> 
                       monoResponseFilters.zipWith(mono).map(...))
```

How can i process my Mono functions only once by 1 Thread inside Flux?

Comment: By applying `flatMap` you do actually get at least as many emits as there is in initial `Flux`. I assume what you actually wanted to use is [collectList()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--), is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that what this task is reads like this:

- Get some values from database
- When all values arrive, wrap them in request and send out
- Zip result with response

Then this leads us to something like this:

```
Flux<Foo> foos = dao.getAll();
Mono<List<Foo>> everything = foos.collectList();

Mono<MyRequest> request = everything
    // collect the data into another Mono, then into request
    .map(list -> list.stream().map(Foo::getData).collect(toList()))
    .map(data -> new MyRequest(data));

return request.zipWhen(request -> api.send(request));
```

Alternatively, you can collect build request a little easier if you map the initial `foos`:

```
Flux<Data> data = dao.getAll().map(Foo::getData);
Mono<MyRequest> request = data.collectList().map(MyRequest::new);
```

Comment: but i need to return Flux<Foo> with changes from MyResponse

Comment: @MaksymShamanovskyi why? If you actually needed to emit several pulses, then this is what original code does, so there's no substance in question. If you do actually need to emit only once, then this is the use case for `Mono<T>`. If you want to conceal how many pulses you do, why not return a `Publisher`? Anyway, there's a `Mono::flux` as well.